# str.format raises KeyError with dict as parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

Look at the code below.

```
s = "{a} {b} {a}"

print(s.format(a=1, b=2))
print(s.format({"a": 1, "b": 2}))
```

The output is:

```
1 2 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(s.format({"a": 1, "b": 2}))
KeyError: 'a'
```

I thought the `str.format(a=1, b=2)` is equal with `str.format({"a": 1, "b": 2})` but it does not looks so.

First way seems terrible if you have to write a lot of parameters (especially if you have several format strings). I prefer 2nd one.

So can I use dict to format string with duplication of `a` parameter? Or any short alternative to avoid of long parameter list inside format method brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to pass the dictionary using named parameter packing or `format` reverts back to positional to display a string representation of your dictionary (would "work" if `s = "{}"` for instance, but not what you want).

```
s.format(**{"a": 1, "b": 2})
```

This is easier to comprehend when using a variable:

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2}
s.format(d)   # tries to shove "d" into 3-param/named format: wrong
s.format(**d) # unpacks arguments. Works because keys are compatible with format string
```